# videos carousel with fullscreen in jquery and html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Good day all.
I would like to make a simple carousel of videos, that when once it's clicked, the carousel stops and the video goes fullscreen until its end, then close.

Actually I have achieved a 70% of this, I'm lacking in the fullscreen part.

the code is :

```
<style>
#carousel {
        width: 480px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #carousel ul {
        width: 1920px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #carousel ul li {
        width:480px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 280px;
        list-style: none;
        float:  left;
    }
</style>


<div id="carousel" >
   <ul>
       <li>
           <video class="media-video" poster="poster1.jpg" controls>
                <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
           </video> 
       </li> 
       <li>
           <video class="media-video" poster="poster2.jpg" controls>
                <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
           </video> 
       </li>
       <li>
           <video class="media-video" poster="poster3.jpg" controls>
                <source src="video3.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
           </video> 
       </li>                                 
  </ul> 
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("media-video");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }


    //carousel

    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
        })
    },5000);
});</script>
```

My problem is that the fullscreen part is seems ignored, no error thrown but anything happens, also, I would like to think something that stops the carousel on play, is there a way I can intercept the clicks and stops the carousel? (then of course start it again at the end), if not, I qill implement a "click to next carousel" insthead of the timing one. But the fullscreen issues is the one I would like to resolve, what I'm mistaking?

EDIT1:

the new code is this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
        })
    },5000);


    $(".media-video" ).bind('play', function () {
        clearInterval(t);
        if (this.requestFullscreen) {
          this.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (this.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          this.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (this.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          this.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }   
    });


    $(".media-video" ).bind('pause', function () {
        t = setInterval(function(){
            $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},2000,function(){
                $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
                $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
            })
        },1000);
    });

});
</script>
```

now the problem is ONLY the fullscreen, which seems to be ignored, no alerts, no warning, no errors.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var t = setInterval(function(){
    $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
        $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    })
},5000);


$(".media-video" ).bind('play', function () {
    clearInterval(t);
```

/*Code below will check if document is in full screen if so cancel it, otherwise request full screen, RunPrefixMethod is used for checking browser based prefixes e.g msIsFullScreen or msFullScreen */

```
if (RunPrefixMethod(document, "FullScreen") || 
        RunPrefixMethod(document, IsFullScreen")) {

        RunPrefixMethod(document, "CancelFullScreen");
}else{
        RunPrefixMethod($("body")[0], "RequestFullScreen");
}


});


$(".media-video" ).bind('pause', function () {
    t = setInterval(function(){
        $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},2000,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
        })
    },1000);
});
```

function RunPrefixMethod(obj, method) {

```
    var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o", ""];
    var p = 0,
        m, t;
    while (p < pfx.length && !obj[m]) {
        m = method;
        if (pfx[p] === "") {
            m = m.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + m.substr(1);
        }
        m = pfx[p] + m;
        t = typeof obj[m];
        if (t !== "undefined") {
            pfx = [pfx[p]];
            return (t === "function" ? obj[m]() : obj[m]);
        }
        p++;
    }
```

});

Comment: really nice I have added the behavior for the start and stop carousel, which is working perfectly, the problem now is the fulscreen.

Comment: OK, when you play a video you are trying to request full screen. So what you can do is $("body")[0], "RequestFullScreen");  Here RequestFullScreen is browser specific e.g prefixed with ms or webkit or moz or o. You can cancel fullscreen using document.CancelFullScreen ,remember to put browser prefix in front of CancelFullScreen for different browsers

Answer (score 0):

From [the spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html):

> If any of the following conditions are true, queue a task to fire an event named fullscreenerror with its bubbles attribute set to true on the context object's node document, and then terminate
>
> …
>
> - This algorithm is not allowed to show a pop-up.

From [the linked spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-pop-up):

> An algorithm is allowed to show a popup if any of the following conditions is true

… followed by a bunch of conditions that can be summarised as "the code to open the popup was trigged by the user".

In short, **you cannot go full screen as the document loads**. You have to do so in response to the user doing something (such as clicking a button).

Comment: which for me is totally ok, I have read those specs, and my diea is to go fullscreen only after the video has begun, and it starts only if the user click play on it...i thought this was enough for that.. :/

Comment: Hmm, you radically changed the code in the question while I was writing this. Before you were trying to go full screen on `ready`.

Comment: Anyway, "the video has started playing" might not be sufficiently user triggered. Try making your own play button that calls `.play()` and the fullscreen functions.